# How to find the maximum of this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have an optimization problem of the form
$$\begin{align} 
\max_{\mathbf{x}} \quad \mathbf{x}^H \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{x} = c
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector of length $M$, $c$ is a scalar, and $\mathbf{A}$ is an invertible and definite positive matrix of $M \times M$. $^H$ is the complex conjugate transpose.

For this problem, the Lagrange multiplier method can be used,
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda) = \mathbf{x}^H \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} + \lambda (\mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{x} - c)
\end{align},$$
we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda)}{\partial \mathbf{x}} &= 2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \lambda \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}, \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\lambda)}{\partial \lambda} &=  \mathbf{b} \mathbf{x} - c = 0
\end{align}.$$
The solution is
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} = \frac{c \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}}
\end{align}.$$
which is the minimum. So, How to find its maximum?

Comment: Are you working on a specific problem? Because to me it seems unlikely a problem of this generality can not include cases where either a max or a min exists.

Comment: @coffeemath Well, Thank you for your comment. I have edited the post about the Lagrange multiplier method. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a inverse marix.

Comment: You have the minimum if and only if $A$ is definite positive.

Comment: @chenxi I see that $A^{-1}$ appears in the formula for $x,$ but that doesn't mean that $A$ is an inverse matrix, only that $A$ has an inverse.

Comment: @NN2 You are right! So, this problem doesn't has the maximum?

Comment: @coffeemath Quite agree, many thanks.